# Neo4j: Suggestions for ways to model a graph with shared nodes but has a unique path based on some property

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying work out the data model for an application I am working on.  The application is currently using Neo4j.

The basic model has 3 types: Course, Test, Questions.  The application allows users to create a course and then relate tests (existing or new) to the course.  They can then, add or remove questions from the test, but this addition and removal should not effect other courses/tests in the graph.

Here are the different models that I have thought of with pros and cons:

1.) Create course node, an edge to the test node, and then on the test to question create/delete edge to the questions with a property on the edge with the course id. With this model the cypher query would look like this:

`match (c:COURSE {id:'123'})<--(t:TEST)-[r]->(q:QUESTION) where r.courseId='123' return c, t, q;`

PROS: Simple data model.  Most obvious solution.

CONS: After a couple hundred edges between 2 node, the performance *really* suffers because there is not 1 simple path from Course to Questions, it needs to evaluate/compare all the edges.

2.) Create course node, an edge to the test node, and then for the edge between the test and question, use the the course id as the *type* of edge.  With this model the cypher query would look something like this:

`match (c:COURSE {id:'123'})<--(t:TEST)-[:123]->(q:QUESTION) return c, t, q;`

PROS: From my research, Neo4j seems to handle this type of modeling better.

CONS: Is there is upper limit on the number of edge types?  Not sure if the performance would be any better than #1 if there are hundreds or thousands of courses.

3.) Create course node, an edge to the test node, and the create just 1 edge with a list of the course ids.  With this model the cypher query would look something like this:

`match (c:COURSE {id:'123'})<--(t:TEST)-[r]->(q:QUESTION) where r.courseIds contains '123' return c, t, q;` (not the correct syntax, but you get the idea)

PROS: Seems pretty simple still

CONS: Not sure if cypher even supports that type of query.  Would a scan through the properties list of a single edge be just as bad as a scan of all the edges with a single property?

4.) Create copies of the tests and questions for each course.

PROS:  Seems to be by far the fastest solution because there is only 1 path and no comparison needed.  Just start with the course and traverse the whole graph.

CONS:  This would result in a lot of redundant data.  Seems like this would defeat the purpose of using a graph and could be better modeled in Cassandra or some other data store.

5.) ??? - Looking for any other suggestion I missed

**Basically, what I am looking for is the best way to create a graph with shared nodes but has a unique path based on some property where the performance isn't on the order of minutes for the traversal to complete for a large number possible property values.**

NOTES:

- I have only implemented #1 and that is how I figured out that the performance of the query is miserable after a couple hundred courses are created.
- I tried to be as clear and complete as possible in the asking of the question, but if I missed something please ask for clarification.
- I have done a lot of looking and I have not come across a good way to model this.

Comment: Shouldn't a single test be associated with only a single course?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a need to store course ids in multiple places and then query for matching ids later.

Here is a simpler model that makes more sense to me. Every `Test` node is related to a single `Course` node, and is related to multiple Question nodes.

To find each Test (and its collection of Questions) for a single Course, the query would look like:

```
MATCH (c:Course {id:'123'})<-[:FOR]-(t:Test)-[:HAS_QUESTION]->(q:Question)
RETURN c, t, COLLECT(q) AS questions;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is MUCH simpler, but doesn't exactly solve the problem.  In your example, when we are creating a Course node, we would also need to create a new test (or multiple tests).  I tried to simplify the model for the asking of this question.

Comment: There is a "master" course for different types of courses with tests and then questions already defined.  When a new course is created, we make a copy of the master (i.e. a course node) that is related to the preexisting tests and questions.  Then, the user can modify those tests and questions as needed.  

In your solution, we would have to create a copy of the tests for each course.  This would be more or less like #4 from the original question.

Comment: Note:  The user can only manipulate the relationships, not the actual values of the nodes, so copying of any kind would result in duplicate data.  I would like to get this done by just changing the edges if at all possible...

Comment: Why that restriction on manipulating only relationships? It can really hamper the finding of a reasonable solution. And can you even *create* nodes?